# Erros de grafia no popover de dicas para resposta de uma pergunta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Existem dois erros de grafia no popover de dicas para resposta de uma pergunta:

> Certifique-se de *responder **a** pergunta*.

O correto seria **à**.

> **Perdir** esclarecimentos ou detalhes sobre outras respostas.

O correto seria **Pedir**.

Comment: Este é o popover que aparece em que circunstâncias, mesmo?

Comment: @JNat, quando você dá foco no campo de resposta de uma pergunta.

Comment: Ah, tá certo: aparece para novos utilizadores, então! Fui lá e não vi, e não me ocorreu logo. Vou ver o que se passa ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Obrigado pelo relatório. Esta string é um "site setting," que só funcionários conseguem alterar. Está corrigida.

---

Thanks for reporting. This string is a site setting, which only developers / CMs can edit. It should be fixed now.

Comment: @JNat Acho que a tradução de "*Thanks for reporting*" seria "*Obrigado por relatar*". Além disso, a palavra "*relatório*", embora seja tradução direta para "*report*", tem uma conotação de algo muito mais rígido e formal na língua portuguesa do que na língua inglesa.

Comment: Um "bug report" não é um "relatório de bug?"

Comment: @JNat Pode ser "*relato de bug*". Mas enfim, isso é coisa para o Portuguese Language.

Answer (score 8):

Não consegui localizar o texto desse popover no [serviço que armazena as traduções](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/) do site. Isso significa que essa tradução deve estar gravada em algum lugar que só os administradores do site (funcionários do Stack Overflow) podem ver. A moderação irá acionar os responsáveis para ver como corrigir.

Answer (score 2):

Concordo com a parte sobre **pedir**, mas discordo com relação à regência verbal do verbo *responder*. O fragmento *"a pergunta"* na frase é complemento verbal, não objeto. Nesse caso o verbo é intransitivo e não cabe o uso de crase.

P.s.: fiquei feliz de descobrir que [temos um *Stack* para a língua portuguesa](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/). Em caso de dúvidas, podemos levar o assunto para lá :)

Comment: "Responder" é intransitivo? Para mim isso é novidade. Vou deixar mais questões sobre o assunto para o Portuguese Language

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado `"Responder" é intransitivo?` Para dar um exemplo, basta eu não responder ;)

Comment: Pode ser intransitivo, mas não nesse contexto. Nesse contexto é transitivo indireto. O que se pode argumentar é que poderia ficar sem o acento considerando que o artigo estaria omitido, e o `a` seria somente preposição. Ou ainda que seria transitivo direto, considerando a mudança linguística que vem ocorrendo no Brasil – posição controversa do ponto de vista normativo. Enfim, assunto pro [portuguese.se] mesmo :)

Comment: [https://www.conjugacao.com.br/regencia-do-verbo-responder/](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/regencia-do-verbo-responder/) - é como o @bfavaretto disse. :)

Comment: Vocês já levaram o assunto para o Portuguese Language ou posso postar lá?

Comment: @LucasGuima sinta-se sempre a vontade para perguntar por lá, Lucas. Eu confesso que sou preguiçoso e só criei um perfil por lá ontem, e mesmo assim nem perguntei nem vi se já foi perguntado.