# Tradução de termos técnicos intraduzíveis

Tags: debate, tradução, tags

Aqui no SOpt nós sempre priorizamos nossa língua. Eu sempre que posso prefiro o termo em português ("printar" -> "imprimir", "debugar" -> "depurar"), mas não dá para traduzir tudo. Acho que nunca escrevi "tratamento" para *trait*, nem "depurador" para *debug*.

Algumas *tags* estão em inglês e outras em português. Algumas provavelmente foram exagero. Não vamos exagerar nem para um lado nem para o outro. Vamos tentar montar uma lista de termos que não deveriam ser traduzidos?

Sugira as palavras que acha que ficam com entendimento pior quando traduzidas.

Avise se você for de Portugal ou outro país com dialeto mais próximo do país europeu, já que nem todos sabem seu *background* cultural, o que pode estranhar algumas pessoas.

Além do nosso uso alguns dos termos poderão ser usados como *blacklist* de tradução na documentação da Microsoft.

> Exemplos: Deploy, Build, Mobile, Release, Model - View - Controller, handlers , binding, Client-side

Comment: Uma por resposta ou várias por resposta?

Comment: Eu acho que vale a sugestão, se alguma criar controvérsia podemos votar individualmente. Acho que aqui podemos só listar, então pode ser tudo junto.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-w0-lZldWA

Comment: Tangencial, mas voto 100% por uso de termos em inglês +  itálico, é a política que tenho adotado para termos técnicos com tradução "estranha" desde a fase do Beta.

Comment: _"Avise se você for de Portugal ou outro país com dialeto mais próximo do país europeu, já que nem todos sabem seu background cultural, o que pode estranhar algumas pessoas."_ - Eu acho que as diferenças linguísticas são fáceis de perceber, pelo menos nunca tive problemas em perceber o vocabulário técnico Brasileiro.

Apesar de termos a localização na bio, será que há uma forma melhor de perceber de forma rápida a "origem" para não estranhar os termos usados?

Comment: @TiagoLeite não sei dizer, mas acho que o mais fácil é a pessoa dizer, não consigo imaginar uma forma mais fácil. pela experiência que tive aqui com alguns "tugas" é que há algumas diferenças que são perceptíveis e dá para inferir a origem cultural da pessoal, mas vai que não fique óbvio. Vi vários usuários no site não conseguem e acham estranho, ou até mesmo errado. Percebeu? Ou como eu diria para um brasileiro, entendeu? :)

Comment: "Valeu" @Maniero! Vou tentar ser o mais neutro possível no que toca aos termos técnicos e se sentir que podem causar acrescento uma pequena nota de rodapé ou escrevo o termo alternativo ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quase todos esses termos têm tradução para o português. Apesar disso, em alguns deles, a tradução para o português é pouco conhecida, obscura e soa estranha aos ouvidos, sendo os termos em inglês mais conhecidos.

## Traduções usuais e consolidadas

- **Annotation** ⇨ **Anotação**.
- **Array** ⇨ **Arranjo** ou **vetor**.
- **Back end** ⇨ **Camada de trás**, **camada do fundo** ou **camada servidora**.
- **Background** ⇨ Dependendo do contexto, pode ser a própria palavra "**contexto**" ou pode ser **segundo plano**, **pano-de-fundo**, **plano de fundo** ou **cor de fundo**. No caso de "background cultural", trata-se de contexto cultural.
- **Binding** ⇨ **Ligação**, no sentido de ligar uma coisa a outra, e não no sentido de chamada telefônica.
- **Blacklist** ⇨ **Lista negra**.
- **Browser** ⇨ **Navegador de internet**.
- **Build** (substantivo) ⇨ **Construção**. Dependendo do contexto onde é utilizado, pode ser traduzido como **compilação** ou **compilado**.
- **Build** (verbo) ⇨ **Construir** ou **compilar**.
- **Client-side** ⇨ **Lado do cliente** ou **camada do cliente**.
- **Chat** ⇨ **Bate-papo**.
- **Deadlock** ⇨ **Impasse**. Apesar disso, esta tradução não é muito precisa, pois no contexto original, se refere a processos que travam porque um está esperando o outro.
- **Debug** (substantivo) ⇨ **Depuração**.
- **Debug** (verbo) ⇨ **Depurar**.
- **Debugger** ⇨ **Depurador**.
- **Deploy** (substantivo) ⇨ **Implantação** ou **distribuição**.
- **Deploy** (verbo) ⇨ **Implantar** ou **distribuir**.
- **Dequeue** ⇨ **Desenfileirar**.
- **Diskette** ⇨ **Disquete**.
- **Enqueue** ⇨ **Enfileirar**.
- **Finish** (substantivo) ⇨ **Finalização**, **fim**, **término**.
- **Finish** (verbo) ⇨ **Finalizar**, **concluir**, **terminar**.
- **Fixture** ⇨ **Contexto de teste**.
- **Foreground** ⇨ **Primeiro plano**. Outras possíveis traduções são **pano de frente** e **plano de frente**.
- **Front end** ⇨ **Camada da frente** ou **camada de apresentação**.
- **Hack** (substantivo) ⇨ Depende da conotação do contexto. Se for algo feio e mal-feito é **gambiarra**. Se for algo para fazer alguma outra coisa funcionar é **remendo**. Se for algo para invadir um sistema ou coisa similar seria um **truque**, uma **burla** ou uma **trapaça**.
- **Kludge** ⇨ **Gambiarra**, **lixo** ou **tranqueira**, dependendo do contexto.
- **Layer** ⇨ **Camada lógica**.
- **Loop** ⇨ **Laço**.
- **Mobile** ⇨ **Móvel**.
- **Model-View-Controller** ⇨ **Modelo-Visão-Controlador**.
- **Queue** ⇨ **Fila**.
- **Release** (substantivo) ⇨ **Liberação** ou **publicação**.
- **Release** (verbo) ⇨ **Liberar** ou **publicar**.
- **Report** (substantivo) ⇨ **Relatório**.
- **Report** (verbo) ⇨ **Relatar**. O verbo "reportar" é um neologismo e um anglicismo, uma forma inadequada (mas não necessariamente incorreta) de traduzir algo do inglês para o português.
- **Restart** (substantivo) ⇨ **Reinício**.
- **Restart** (verbo) ⇨ **Reiniciar**.
- **Schedule** (substantivo) ⇨ **Escala** ou **agendamento**.
- **Schedule** (verbo) ⇨ **Escalar** ou **escalonar** ou **agendar**.
- **Scheduler** ⇨ **Escalonador** ou **agendador**.
- **Server-side** ⇨ **Lado do servidor** ou **camada do servidor**.
- **Set** (substantivo) ⇨ **Conjunto**.
- **Set** (verbo) ⇨ **Definir**.
- **Shutdown** (substantivo) ⇨ **Desligamento**, **parada** ou **queda**.
- **Shutdown** (verbo) ⇨ **Desligar**, **parar** ou **cair**. Nesse caso, frequentemente a solução é buscar um sinônimo que se encaixe bem no contexto e traduzir esse sinônimo ao invés de traduzir diretamente.
- **Stack** ⇨ **Pilha**.
- **Start** (substantivo) ⇨ **Início**.
- **Start** (verbo) ⇨ **Iniciar**.
- **Tier** ⇨ **Camada física**.
- **Trojan** ⇨ **Cavalo de Troia**.
- **Warning** ⇨ **Advertência** ou **aviso**.
- **Waterfall model** ⇨ **Modelo cascata**.
- **Web** ⇨ **Rede**.
- **Whitelist** ⇨ **Lista branca**.
- **Wildcard** ⇨ **Curinga**.
- **Winchester** ⇨ **HD**. O termo "winchester" caiu em desuso (mesmo no inglês) e foi substituído por HD (que significa *Hard Disk*). No português acabou ficando o "agá-dê".
- **Workaround** ⇨ **Solução de contorno**.
- **World wide web** ⇨ **Rede mundial de computadores**.

## Traduções incomuns

- **Blockchain** ⇨ A tradução literal e conceitualmente correta seria **cadeia de blocos**. Entretanto, nunca vi alguém usando esse termo traduzido.
- **Closure** ⇨ **Fechamento**, embora poucas vezes vi esse termo sendo traduzido.
- **Deque** ⇨ **Fila de duas cabeças**, embora seja difícil eu ver alguém tentando traduzir isso.
- **Firewall** ⇨ **Parede de fogo**. Embora nunca vi ninguém usando essa tradução.
- **Framework** ⇨ **Arcabouço**. Já vi quem sugerisse como tradução **quadro de trabalho**.
- **Full stack** ⇨ É difícil traduzir-se esse termo adequadamente, vez que a tradução literal **pilha completa** soa estranha, embora já tenha visto sendo usada e está conceitualmente correta. Uma outra possibilidade é **em todas as camadas**.
- **Go Horse** ⇨ Vai cavalinho! Mais gambiarras para termos mais bugs! Poderia ser traduzido como **vai cavalo**, mas não dá para usar essa tradução de forma séria.
- **Handle** (substantivo) ⇨ **Maçaneta**, **puxador** ou **manipulação**. Soa muito estranho, embora seja correto.
- **Handle** (verbo) ⇨ **Manipular**.
- **Handler** ⇨ **Manipulador**. Embora exista, nunca vi ninguém usando a tradução porque soa estranho pacas, embora seja correta. Na verdade, o termo em inglês também é algo um tanto duvidoso, vez que na maioria das vezes que temos um `FooHandler`, trata-se do nome de uma coisa que ninguém sabe definir direito o que é exatamente, mas que é usada para acessar-se ou *manipular-se* `Foo`s.
- **Mock** (em testes de unidade) ⇨ **Imitação**. Entretanto, nunca vi ninguém usando isso traduzido.
- **Pool** ⇨ A tradução "piscina" ou "tanque" não faz nenhum sentido no português. Traduções razoáveis, mas mesmo assim pouco usadas e que podem não se encaixar bem no contexto seriam **reservatório** ou **reserva**.
- **Tag** ⇨ **Etiqueta**. Entretanto, raramente essa tradução é pertinente ou adequada.
- **Trait** ⇨ **Feição**.

## Palavras incorporadas ao português tal como no original

- **Bug** (substantivo) ⇨ Não costuma se traduzir e está sendo incorporado ao português. Dependendo do contexto, pode ser substituído por **defeito de software** ou **erro de programação**. Mas alguns usos não são traduzidos como por exemplo, "bug do milênio".
- **Bug** (verbo) ⇨ **Dar erro** ou **dar pau**. Está sendo incorporado ao português (verbo **bugar**).
- **E-mail** ⇨ Seria **correio eletrônico**, mas esse termo me traz velhas lembranças dos anos 199X, quase ninguém mais fala "correio eletrônico" hoje em dia.
- **Firmware** ⇨ Foi incorporada ao português dessa forma. É um conjunto de instruções programadas diretamente dentro de um chip.
- **Hack** (verbo) ⇨ Já entrou na língua portuguesa como **hackear**. Eu hackeio, tu hackeias, ele hackeia, nós hackeamos, vós hackeais, eles hackeiam. Significa invadir ou burlar o funcionamento de algum programa de computador, sistema, site ou rede.
- **Hacker** ⇨ Hacker não é "aquele que faz hacks". É uma **pessoa que consegue (ou ao menos tenta) invadir sistemas ou violar a segurança dos mesmos**. Não necessariamente é um inimigo externo, pode ser alguém que trabalha na equipe de desenvolvimento de sistemas procurando por possíveis falhas para serem corrigidas.
- **Hardware** ⇨ Foi incorporada ao português dessa forma. Às vezes é traduzido como **equipamento**, embora o conceito de "equipamento" seja bem mais amplo do que "hardware".
- **Internet** ⇨ Ninguém muda o nome disso. Já foi incorporado ao português. A tradução seria **rede mundial de computadores**.
- **Software** ⇨ Foi incorporada ao português dessa forma. A tradução seria **programa de computador**.
- **Scrum** ⇨ A palavra está sendo adotada no português dessa forma. É o nome de uma metodologia ágil de desenvolvimento de software (embora possa ser usado em alguns outros casos que não desenvolvimento de software).
- **Spam** ⇨ Foi incorporado ao português dessa forma. Se você usa a internet há mais do que uns poucos meses, você já deve saber muito bem o que é isso e já deve ter aprendido a odiá-lo (exceto se você for um spammer, veja o termo abaixo). É uma mensagem não-solicitada, enviada de forma abusiva visando atingir grande número de pessoas. Tem uma conotação extremamente negativa. Curiosamente, o significado original dela mesmo no inglês nada tem a ver com isso, tratava-se do nome de uma marca de comida enlatada.
- **Spammer** ⇨ Criatura inferior, odiável e maldita das trevas que vive no submundo da internet como um parasita para trazer discórdia, maldição, tormento, dor e sofrimento ao criar incansavelmente uma infindável quantidade de puro lixo (vide spam) congestionando toda a internet.
- **Thread** ⇨ Foi incorporada ao português dessa forma. A tradução literal seria "linha", no sentido de linha de costura, algo mais fino que uma corda, mas essa tradução não faz sentido no contexto de computação.

## Termos que não tem como traduzir

- **Adware** ⇨ Programa de computador com a finalidade de exibir propagandas/anúncios. Tem uma conotação negativa. Difícil de se definir em uma única palavra.
- **Crash** ⇨ É o famoso **deu pau**. Normalmente evita-se usar esse termo no português e acaba-se ou usando o termo original em inglês ou então substitui-se ele por uma outra expressão sinônima que descreva o fenômeno no contexto: **deu pau**, **bugou**, **deu um erro**, algum tipo de palavrão, etc.
- **Cookie** ⇨ Traduzir isso como "biscoito" ou "bolacha" seria tolo. [*Tenha cuidado ao usar este termo no português.*](https://vidadeprogramador.com.br/2013/08/07/cookie/)
- **Heap** ⇨ A tradução seria "monte", no sentido de "monte de feno". Não faz muito sentido no português a tradução.
- **Kanban** ⇨ Diferente das demais, essa palavra vem do japonês, e não do inglês. A tradução literal seria "cartão" ou "sinalização", mas ninguém tenta traduzir isso.
- **Stub** ⇨ A tradução literal seria "toco", mas essa tradução não faz sentido aos ouvidos de ninguém.

## Desconheço qualquer tentativa de tradução decente

- **Batch** ⇨ Processo assíncrono executado em **background**.
- **Callback** ⇨ Mecanismo utilizado para que uma função/procedimento/método chame uma outra função/procedimento/método que lhe é informado como parâmetro. A tradução "chamar de volta" é inadequada, principalmente quando isso for usado como substantivo.
- **Crack** (substantivo) ⇨ Intrusão, quebra, violação, burla. Nenhuma dessas é uma boa tradução que tem a mesma conotação do termo em inglês.
- **Crack** (verbo) ⇨ Intrudir, quebrar, violar, burlar. Nenhuma dessas é uma boa tradução que tem a mesma conotação do termo em inglês.
- **Cracker** ⇨ Intruso, hacker mal intencionado ou que viola ou burla mecanismos de segurança. Difícil definir de forma precisa em uma só palavra.
- **Cluster** ⇨ ...
- **Exploit** (substantivo) ⇨ Software utilizado para aproveitar-se de uma brecha ou falha de segurança. Difícil definir-se com uma só palavra.
- **Exploit** (verbo) ⇨ Aplicar um exploit (substantivo). Aproveitar-se de uma brecha ou falha de segurança por meio de um software desenvolvido com tal finalidade. Difícil definir-se com uma só palavra.
- **Getter** ⇨ É o nome que se dá a um tipo de método que produz um valor.
- **Grid** ⇨ ...
- **Harness** ⇨ É o nome dado aos frameworks de testes automatizados. A tradução literal seria "arreio", um equipamento utilizado em montaria de cavalos.
- **Livelock** ⇨ Algo parecido com o deadlock, mas um pouco diferente. O resultado é praticamente o mesmo, mas os processos não estão a rigor travados, podendo executar outras atividades enquanto não obtém acesso ao recurso indisponível. Mas ainda assim, os processos não conseguem realizar progresso no andamento de suas tarefas por estarem esperando recursos travados em uma situação de impasse.
- **Malware** ⇨ Frequentemente é traduzido como vírus e em grande parte dos casos a tradução serve, mas para ser exato, vírus é uma subcategoria de malwares, pois nem todos os malwares são vírus.
- **Middleware** ⇨ Um framework ou coisa parecida responsável pelo envio e recebimento de mensagens ou para a abstração de chamadas de procedimentos remotos em um sistema distribuído.
- **Mainframe** ⇨ ...
- **Ransomware** ⇨ A pior coisa que as mentes mais doentias que já existiram na internet foram capazes de inventar. É um tipo de malware que sequestra os dados/arquivos da vítima tornando-os inacessíveis e exigindo um pagamento em dinheiro para devolvê-los (e não espere que ele seja honesto e vá de fato restaurar os arquivos após o pagamento ser efetuado).
- **Setter** ⇨ É o nome que se dá a um tipo de método que define um valor.
- **Shebang** ⇨ É o nome dado aos dois caracteres `#!` ao início do código-fonte de um programa de uma linguagem de programação interpretada.
- **Socket** ⇨ Abstração utilizada em linguagens de programação para enviar ou receber dados em uma rede de computadores. Difícil de se definir em uma única palavra.
- **Spyware** ⇨ Tipo de malware que tem como finalidade espionar o usuário do computador/dispositivo onde está instalado. Tem uma conotação negativa. Difícil de se definir em uma única palavra.

---

Observação: Esta resposta está marcada como wiki da comunidade. Sinta-se livre para editar e acrescentar os termos que achar melhor.

Comment: _Crack_ vem de quebrar mesmo, ainda mais quando aplicado a segurança.

Comment: @JefersonQuesado Sim, eu sei. Mas chamar um crack de uma quebra é no mínimo estranho. Chamar crackear de quebrar é no mínimo confuso e impreciso.

Comment: Quebra eu vejo mais usdo para o "crash". E deploy tem relação com distribuir, não especificamente a implantação em si (implantação me dá a impressão de induzir o leitor a pensar em "instalação"). Quando vc publica um app na loja, ja é deploy (o que faz sentido "dicionárico" :) http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deploy ).

Comment: "Fixture" se não me engano é um _portmanteau_ de "fix" e "feature", não é? Se sim, então é tão intraduzível quanto "aborrescente" é para inglês

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Baseando-me na resposta de uma pergunta dos nossos irmãos do [SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071344/what-are-fixtures-in-programming) _O objetivo de um [test fixture] é garantir que exista um ambiente bem conhecido e fixo no qual os testes são executados para que os resultados sejam repetíveis. Algumas pessoas chamam isso de contexto de teste. - (traduzido via Google Translate)_ Portanto diria que _contexto de teste_ pode ser aceite. Também vi _dispositivo de teste_ a aparecer nas traduções automáticas mas não me soa correto.

Comment: @TiagoLeite Obrigado. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Como não "sou do meio" tenho receio em colaborar já que não tenho a certeza se os termos que uso são os normalmente aceites/usados em Portugal. Feita a ressalva, em Portugal, *foreground* e *background* será primeiro plano e segundo plano, quando aplicados a processo/execução.

Comment: @ramaral É, havia esquecido desses (com tantos termos assim, fica difícil lembrar direito de todos). São usuais aqui no Brasil também.

Comment: @Bacco Incorporei ao texto também.

Comment: _Pool_ também tem a tradução de reservatório ou tanque. Faz mais sentido que uma "piscina de conexões/threads". Eu classificaria como incomum.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Não confunda "*deque*" com "*dequeue*".

Comment: @Piovezan Editado.

Comment: Em [outro post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6901/4924), surgiu a dúvida sobre a tradução de ***reporting***.

Comment: @ramaral Correto! Em PT-PT o equivalente mais comum a _fore/background_é _primeiro/segundo_ plano.

Comment: @LucasGuima tradução direta seria "reportagem" mas isso não me soa correto. Poderemos a assumir que _reporting_ é _reportar_?

Comment: @TiagoLeite, adicionaram "report" na resposta como "Relatório" e "Relatar".

Comment: @VictorStafusa Estou com uma dúvida numa palavra. Da palavra *Set*? Que muitos abrasileiram como "setar"?

Comment: @danieltakeshi Resposta editada.

Comment: @MateusSchroederdaSilva Resposta editada.

Comment: Antigamente o NetBeans traduzia o *deploy* como **depositar**.

Comment: @Dherik Eu diria que essa é uma tradução muito infeliz e incorreta.