# Podemos ter listas de compras no SOpt?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Já houve uma [tentativa de aceitar listas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/819/101) antes no site. Foi feito de uma forma um pouco forçada, teve muita discussão em chat, a SE pelo CM e o GCM fizeram de uma forma como se a comunidade não pudesse decidir o caminho, não ofereceram alternativas, não quiseram discutir de fato e no fim elas nunca forma aceitas seja uma forma ou outra. Se eles soubesse dialogar provavelmente teria saído um resultado positivo ali e outras discussões sobre isso. Note que eu tentei fazer algo produtivo e estou tentando de novo agora para a comunidade decidir sem parecer uma imposição (ali não fica claro, houve atitudes forçadas em outros pontos em perguntas que já foram removidas porque eram só listas de compras).

## Problemas das listas de compras

Este tipo de "pergunta" foge da filosofia de um site de perguntas e respostas e fere diversas regras e cultura da comunidade.

Atrai perguntas ruins principalmente porque elas são populares e fáceis de fazer, e a gamificação incentiva demais as pessoas abusarem disto. O mesmo vale para respostas.

O principal motivo das respostas serem ruins é que qualquer um pode dar um resposta acéfala e receber muitos votos não por mérito da resposta mas sim pelo mérito que o *link* ou o objeto colocado ali.

Outro motivo importante é que, ao contrário do que o antigo CM sempre defendeu, isto é a definição do que é baseado em opinião. É algo de extrema subjetividade e violam os 6 pontos de [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101).

Claro, perguntas assim podem ser feitas de uma forma que seja construtiva, mas é raro alguém fazê-lo e mais ainda as pessoas que vão responder cumprir os requisitos da pergunta (hoje temos muito conteúdo que as pessoas não se comprometem, é pior que antes).

E um problema é que nenhuma resposta pode ser aceita com propriedade, é praticamente uma loteria.

Então listas de compras viram um festival de de respostas inúteis só para ganhar reputação e/ou fazer de conta que está ajudando, criando a ilusão para alguns que aquilo é bom.

## Listas são legais

Aqui e ali temos exemplos bons em toda rede, vou destacar uma no SOen: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/221800) ([outra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22873/221800), [uma mais específica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1669/221800)). Nós tivemos uma que chegou perto disto: [Existem ambientes online de aprendizagem de programação com exercícios práticos e desafios para C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39415/101). Um exemplo do que não é uma lista boa pode ser vista em: [O que fazer com perguntas que não são mais consideradas boas para a comunidade?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7856/101).

Note não são aceitas perguntas ou respostas de listas de compras, apenas temos postagens visíveis de listas de compras.

- Estas postagens são controladas integralmente pela comunidade e não por um usuário
- estão bloqueadas para garantir isto e são marcada como Community Wiki
- só tem uma pergunta feita com propriedade e explicando como funciona este tip ode *post*
- geralmente a discussão do que deve entrar na resposta é feita no meta.

Eu sempre critiquei o fato da SE não ter ferramentas melhores para lidar com isso e acho que que deveria rever várias coisas para ter um site que ajude desenvolvedores de forma mais geral e não só como um Q&A (que por sinal hoje já é bem deturpado de um jeito ruim). Mas podemos fazer algo com o que temos.

Mas o conteúdo de listas é muito procurado, é útil, atende  o requisito de termos informações canônicas (prefiro isto que a maioria das perguntas atuais que são só *help desk* bobo de quem não tem a menor condição de programar e a pergunta só vai ajudar essa pessoa).

## Sugestão de funcionamento

Pra começarmos discutir, só vou colocar algumas coisas.

- Um *post* deste só pode ser feito no site principal por um moderador eleito e só estes poderão atualizá-los.
- Estes *posts* CW seguirão a fórmula citada acima de ter uma pergunta e resposta canônica com a lista e estará bloqueado.
- Um conteúdo novo deve ser aberto por discussão no meta (qualquer um pode iniciar, mas a moderação comunitárias ou de diamante poderá editar para deixar uma forma mais adequada.
- Após a discussão e usuários com boa reputação no assunto ou outros que tenham conhecimento notório do assunto irão opinar no que deve entrar na lista. A escolha pode levar em consideração a votação de itens, mas não tem obrigação de seguir isto, o objetivo não é listar o popular e sim o que tem qualidade.
- Nada entra sem alguma argumentação porque aquilo é válido (alguns itens podem entrar com ressalvas).
- Só porque o assunto foi discutido não obriga gerar um *post*.
- "Perguntas" postadas por um usuário nesse modelo será fechadas e eventualmente removidas normalmente, embora uma discussão no meta pode ser inciada por cauda disto.
- Eventualmente podemos ter adicionalmente um chat para essas discussões.
- Ninguém ganhará reputação por isso.
- Fica claro que *spam* será evitado.

Precisaremos discutir que listas serão aceitas. Livros é a opção óbvia. Já blogs, chats, vídeos, *links* diversos, cursos, tecnologias e outras coisas do tipo nem sempre podem ser desejáveis. Alguns podem ser agrupados por sub comunidade para não ficar com muitos *posts*, alguns com poucos itens.

O ideal seria estes *posts* receber muitos votos para ficar mais destacado, mas não é fácil resolver isso (me parece que o motivo abaixo deixa votar sem computar reputação), mas os votos não podem contar reputação para os usuários.

Como seria o bloqueio (precisamos traduzir):

[image: Resposta comunitária]

## Conclusão

Sugiro entender o problema melhor visitando os *links* para entender o problemas, leia tudo lá, já teve um debate sobre isto.

Dê uma resposta ou pelo menos comente além de votar em algo pata entendermos o que você pensa, principalmente moderadores que terão a tarefa de administrar isso.

As regras específicas podem ser definidas depois, mas linhas gerais do funcionamento podem ser dadas agora.

Não estou propondo aceitar perguntas que pedem listas.

Vale o esforço? Você participaria disto? Acha que teríamos participação suficiente pra fazer isto funcionar? Os benefícios supram os problemas? O que mais acrescentaria?

Usaríamos estes para fechar como duplicatas ou perguntas do tipo deveriam ser fechadas por outro motivo e até removidas? Tenho minha preferência :)

<sub>Eu mudei de opinião em relação a algumas coisas, não me lembro se no passado os exemplos estavam colocados de uma forma ruim.</sub>

Comment: Me parece que seria só trazer mais problemas, se hoje tem muitas perguntas/respostas ruins para moderar, não acho que precise de mais trabalho para os moderadores (mas não sou um, nem nunca fui, não sei se pra vocês ta tranquilo, mas parece que não, já que uma ou outra fila de análise tá quase sempre cheia, isso que não precisa ser moderador para moderar elas). Colocar links nas wikis de tags, como já é feito (em algumas), parece a melhor solução. Seria mais útil pensar em uma forma de chamar mais a atenção dos usuários que não conhecem para as wikis e páginas de ajuda (minha opinião, é claro)

Comment: Eu adoro as "listas de compras" do github, que sempre começam com "awesome-xxxxxxx". Existem inúmeras [listas awesomes](https://www.google.com/search?q=github+awesome) e eu sempre procuro por elas. São ótimos pontos de partida para qualquer projeto/ideia nova que precisem ser pesquisados.

Comment: @danieltakeshi a ideia seria esta, mas parece que o pessoal não está muito interessado.

Comment: O exemplo mais próximo de lista awesome que possuímos é do tópico de [termos técnicos intraduzíveis](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6971/75104). Acho que estas listas dariam certo se precisassem da aprovação de membros com algum tipo de medalha (ouro) ou pontuação mínima. Para não ter qualquer tipo de listas no SO... Mas que os membros pudessem sugerir este tipo de lista. Além de ser SEO friendly...

Answer (score 4):

Um resumo do que eu acho sobre a [Como podemos lidar com as "listas"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/819/5878)

> O problema é que essas "listas" são acusadas de diversas coisas:
>
> - Subjetivas demais
> - Baseadas em opinião
> - Impossíveis de se manter
> - Muito específicas

**Subjetivas demais?** Sim, principalmente quando não são definidas regras claras que delimitam o escopo da lista. Qual material pode ser listado na lista? Qual não pode? Quando deve ser incluído? Quando deve ser removido? Se restringido todos os pontos que deixam a lista subjetiva ela passa a ser tão restrita que nem vejo como tirar proveito em fazê-las. **Baseadas em opinião?** Sem dúvidas. O objetivo da lista é exclusivamente listar conteúdos de qualidade sobre determinado assunto, mas quem determinaria o que são conteúdos de qualidade? Aquilo que pode ser bom para mim pode ser ruim para outras pessoas, qual delas deve prevalecer? **Impossíveis de se manter?** Praticamente sim. Conteúdos novos são gerados aos montes todos os dias, quem irá ficar responsável por atualizar a lista adicionando conteúdos novos? Quem ficará responsável por analisar conteúdo já presente na lista para averiguar se ainda são válidos ou estão obsoletos? **Muito específicas?** Não necessariamente, mas entra em conflito com o primeiro item. Ou é subjetiva demais, ou específica demais. Se nenhuma dessas se encaixa nas nossas necessidades, não vejo como utilizar as listas de uma forma saudável para a comunidade.

Se entendi corretamente todas as opiniões dadas lá, foi consenso que as listas não agregariam à comunidade. Foi então concluída a discussão com o Gabe/Shog definindo que poderiam ser utilizadas as Wiki de cada tag para absorver o que seriam as listas e de certa forma tem sido feito isso até então. Por que mudar?

Por mais que vejo exatamente os mesmos problemas em fazer a lista dentro das Wiki, acho que elas são menos impactantes no site que uma pergunta/resposta, que foge completamente do formato do site. Uma pergunta que não é uma pergunta e resposta que não responde a "não-pergunta".

Agora, quanto a sugestão neste tópico...

> **Sugestão de funcionamento**
>
> Pra começarmos discutir, só vou colocar algumas coisas.
>
> - Um post deste só pode ser feito no site principal por um moderador
>     eleito e só estes poderão atualizá-los.
> - Estes posts CW seguirão a fórmula citada acima de ter uma pergunta e resposta canônica com a lista e estará bloqueado.
> - Um conteúdo novo deve ser aberto por discussão no meta (qualquer um pode iniciar, mas a moderação comunitárias ou de diamante poderá editar para deixar uma forma mais adequada.
> - Após a discussão e usuários com boa reputação no assunto ou outros que tenham conhecimento notório do assunto irão opinar no que deve entrar na lista.
> - A escolha pode levar em consideração a votação de itens, mas não tem obrigação de seguir isto, o objetivo não é listar o popular e sim o que tem qualidade.
> - Nada entra sem alguma argumentação porque aquilo é válido (alguns itens podem entrar com ressalvas).
> - Só porque o assunto foi discutido não obriga gerar um post.
> - "Perguntas" postadas por um usuário nesse modelo será fechadas e eventualmente removidas normalmente, embora uma discussão no meta pode ser inciada por cauda disto.
> - Eventualmente podemos ter adicionalmente um chat para essas discussões.
> - Ninguém ganhará reputação por isso.
> - Fica claro que spam será evitado.

**Um post deste só pode ser feito no site principal por um moderador eleito e só estes poderão atualizá-los.**

Sou contra. Acho que deve ser de exclusividade dos moderadores apenas as atividades moderatórias. Parece óbvio, mas não é. Uma das vantagens do formato do Stack Overflow é ser "auto-moderado", em que a comunidade pode se moderar conforme a sua própria necessidade. Uma pergunta é fechada se a comunidade acha que deve ser fechada; reaberta se a mesma acha que pode ser reaberta; etc. Algo que depende diretamente do interesse da comunidade não deveria ser controlado exclusivamente pelos moderadores. Não acho que isso cabe como uma função dos moderadores.

**Estes posts CW seguirão a fórmula citada acima de ter uma pergunta e resposta canônica com a lista e estará bloqueado.**

Sou contra. Não vejo porque utilizar uma pergunta para algo que não é uma pergunta e uma resposta que não responde a "não-pergunta". O fato da lista não caber no formato do site indica que possivelmente não deveria estar presente no site. Não vi justificativas para mudar isso.

**Um conteúdo novo deve ser aberto por discussão no meta (qualquer um pode iniciar, mas a moderação comunitárias ou de diamante poderá editar para deixar uma forma mais adequada.**

Seria a favor, mas sejamos francos, isso não funcionaria. Basta analisar como é a participação da comunidade no Meta. Dá para contar nos dedos os usuários que participam ativamente e mesmo assim não é tão ativamente quanto gostaríamos. Não tem nem como contabilizar o número de discussões abertas no Meta que nunca foram concluídas porque teve uma ou duas opiniões apenas. Depender isso para definir cada tópico de cada lista não teríamos nunca uma lista. Nem vejo porque iniciarmos esse trabalho.

**Após a discussão e usuários com boa reputação no assunto ou outros que tenham conhecimento notório do assunto irão opinar no que deve entrar na lista.**

Aqui entra parte da subjetividade que comentei sobre a outra pergunta. Como avaliar se um usuários está apto a opinar sobre o assunto? Ter reputação alta não pode ser parâmetro, pois o usuário pode ter obtido a reputação em outras tags e não ter conhecimento sobre a tag em questão (eu posso me por de exemplo, pois estou entre os usuários com maior reputação e não tenho conhecimento suficiente para opinar sobre C# ou R). Depender do bom senso do usuário será complicado e sabemos que, por mais que seja menos notório, devemos considerar o efeito Dunning-Kruger. Isso sem contar que a reputação no site não reflete o conhecimento real do usuário, podendo acontecer de ter pontuação alta e não saber ou saber mesmo tendo reputação baixa. A questão de conhecimento notório é tão sensível quanto. Notório para quem? É bastante complicado definir métricas mensuráveis que possam ser utilizadas.

**A escolha pode levar em consideração a votação de itens, mas não tem obrigação de seguir isto, o objetivo não é listar o popular e sim o que tem qualidade.**

Levar em consideração a votação seria o mais correto a se fazer, mas também sabemos que isso não é uma métrica confiável. A ideia da lista é listar qualidade, mas não temos como garantir que quem está avaliando sabe avaliar. Não precisa de muito para se confirmar isso, basta analisar o próprio mercado, que tecnologias são utilizadas mais pela popularidade do que pela qualidade. Para analisar a qualidade real de cada tópico de cada lista seriam necessárias análises técnicas a fundo sobre aquele tópico e uma pergunta assim se encaixa mais no site principal do que no Meta. Se eu vou avaliar, por exemplo, se um artigo é bom o suficiente para entrar na lista eu precisaria levantar todos os pontos positivos e todos os negativos justificando cada um. Ao meu ver, se fosse fazer isso, seria melhor deixar isso no próprio SOpt do que no Meta, pois seria uma pergunta com uma resposta canônica válida.

**Nada entra sem alguma argumentação porque aquilo é válido (alguns itens podem entrar com ressalvas).**

Como comentado no item anterior, a pergunta se algo é válido para entrar na lista seria uma pergunta muito bem definida que demanda de uma resposta canônica. Exatamente o formato que buscamos para o SOpt. Se é uma pergunta técnica que demanda uma resposta técnica, argumentativa e canônica, por que não tê-la no site ao invés do Meta?

**Só porque o assunto foi discutido não obriga gerar um post.**

Natural que seja assim, mas como comentado anteriormente, quem iria avaliar o que entra ou não?

**"Perguntas" postadas por um usuário nesse modelo será fechadas e eventualmente removidas normalmente, embora uma discussão no meta pode ser inciada por cauda disto.**

Isso seria intrinsecamente resolvido se não utilizarmos perguntas para as listas. Ou não utilizarmos listas...

**Eventualmente podemos ter adicionalmente um chat para essas discussões.**

Sou contra. Se algo depender de um chat para ser resolvido ele claramente não cabe no formato do site. Ou é algo que pode ser "discutido" a ponto de possuir uma resposta canônica ou não cabe no site.

**Ninguém ganhará reputação por isso.**

Com o gerenciamento da lista, acho válido. Isso resolveria a questão de criarem listas para tudo, sem necessidade. Mas, considerando as considerações consideradas anteriormente, algo poderia entrar na lista apenas quando provado o mérito por uma resposta canônica. Acho justo que o autor dessa resposta possa ser recompensado de alguma forma.

**Fica claro que spam será evitado.**

Sempre será.

Dito tudo isso, aquilo que procuramos na lista já pode ser resolvido dentro do formato atual do site. A Wiki de cada tag já disponibiliza um formato que pode ser usado para a lista, pois já é única para aquela tag e não impacta diretamente na gamificação do site. Tem o problema de que qualquer usuário possa editar, mas acho que os benefícios em utilizá-la vencem os malefícios. E a administração do conteúdo nestas listas poderia se dar através de perguntas no próprio site sendo que a pergunta precisa ser clara e possuir uma resposta canônica que justifique a qualidade daquele conteúdo.

Resumindo, se for realmente para mantermos algum tipo de lista na comunidade, na minha opinião:

- Usar a própria Wiki de cada tag para concentrar os links;
- A Wiki já é única para cada tag, o que evita misturar conteúdos na lista;
- A Wiki é moderada pela própria comunidade;

  - O que é positivo, pois não dependeríamos de moderadores;
  - O que é negativo, pois poderia haver conflitos de interesse (ainda precisaria ser resolvido);
- A lista só permitir links oficiais, como documentação ou
- A lista só permitir links para perguntas do próprio site, abertas e respondidas;

E, assim, podemos "garantir" a qualidade mínima da lista, dado que a resposta à pergunta já demonstraria o porquê o conteúdo é válido e já podemos filtrar o conteúdo com as outras ferramentas do site: pergunta não clara, fora do escopo, baseado em opinião, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Como houve pouca adesão e algumas críticas (também sem muita adesão), que eu ainda acho que não são mais válidas, são especulações do que poderia acontecer sem vermos de fato se aconteceria e se acontecer não sei se é um real problema, acho que os problemas do site são outros e acho até que em parte isto poderia ajudar melhorar alguns aspectos, eu decidi que não vou fazer nada sobre o assunto, quem sabe um dia isso mude. Se alguém tiver algo a acrescentar ainda tem uns dias de destaque. Acho que não será feito por WO.