# Podemos ter perguntas "oficialmente" canônicas?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Eu sempre gostei de respostas canônicas, ou que servem para todos aprenderem algo. Eu nunca escondi que prefiro o estilo wiki do que fórum do site.

Alguns sites criaram uma forma de resolver isto marcando perguntas como canônicas de alguma forma. [O Superuser por exemplo tem uma meta *tag* que indica que a pergunta é uma FAQ](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8896/does-a-list-of-canonical-questions-for-super-user-exist).

Acham que devemos ter algo semelhante? E qual deveria ser o procedimento?

Não sou fã de meta *tags*, mas admito violar isso se for do interesse da comunidade. Se não usar isto, o que poderíamos fazer para marcar essas perguntas? Ou não deveríamos marcar, mas manter uma lista separada?

Se for para manter a lista separada, exclusivamente ou adicionalmente a marcar as perguntas, como deveria ser? Uma pergunta wiki no site principal com a lista? Esta lista deveria estar no meta? Deveria estar na wiki da *tag* relacionada?

Quais os procedimentos para determinar quais perguntas devem ser canônicas? Quem faria isto?

Acham que deveríamos fazer algo diferente?

Comment: O que é uma pergunta canônica?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260464/101

Comment: Essa "lista separada" seria a "lista de compras" da outra discussão?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não necessariamente, estou deixando aberto pra sugestões de como seria, de qualquer forma não seria igual, até porque lá seria uma lista de coisas externas, e esta seria uma lista de perguntas existentes aqui. Lembrando que estou abrindo o debate não colocando o que eu acho que deve ser feito.

Answer (score 1):

Concordo contigo. No local esquerdo da página poderia ser adicionado o botão "Aprenda" com esses tópicos separados por linguagem e nível de complexidade do conteúdo.

Os tópicos canonizados precisariam ser escolhidos a dedo pela administração, seria um trabalho bastante penoso, a pergunta que fica é se o custo x benefício valeria a pena para o stackoverflow.

Comment: Isso que você relatou já foi aplicado no SOen como ["Stack Overflow Documentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) e foi desativado porque não deu muito certo. Acho que aqui a discussão é um pouco diferente disso e provavelmente está mais relacionada à [Podemos ter listas de compras no SOpt?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7855/5878)

Answer (score 0):

Como não houve um posicionamento claro da comunidade e de como isto poderia ser efetuado acho que fica postergado até haver mais interesse em fazer algo pra melhorar o destaque do que é bom. Ainda fica aberto para quem quiser tentar fazer sugestões.