# Vamos colocar perguntas canônicas nas descrições das tags?

Tags: debate, tags, perguntas, wikis-de-tags

A pergunta é um pouco retórica. Normalmente eu pergunto e nada acontece. Resolvi partir para a ação e se as pessoas quiserem que não faça terá que mostrar aqui porque isso é melhor.

Estou começando pegar as principais perguntas feitas em cada *tag* e colocoar *links* lá na descrição delas para os usuários começarem buscar informação básica ali, inclusive de coisas que no fundo fundo são duplicatas.

Acho que a comunidade deve ajudar, principalmente os maiores respondedores de certas *tags*.

Não podemos exagerar e colocar qualquer pergunta, mas coisas que sempre são perguntas, erros comuns, informações que dão uma definição inicial interessante para o assunto já devem estar lá na *tag*. Acho que as *tags* mais gerais, mais usadas, podem ter um pouco mais de *links*, mas se tiver demais começa tornar inútil. Com o tempo pra colocar uma nova tem que tirar alguma.

E acho que a comunidade deve editar mais para colocar as *tags* corretas na pergunta. Além disto começar indicar mais a leitura das descrições das *tags* pra pessoa que ainda está muito crua no assunto tenha alguma base.

O critério básico é que as perguntas colocadas lá precisam ser aquelas que costumam ser úteis em boa parte dos casos, que é comum ter que *linkar* para indicar algo para as pessoas.

Um exemplo é quando a pessoa sofre de SQL Injection ([veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-injection/info), depois da edição inicial melhore lá), pode indicar a descrição da *tag* que pode ter as principais perguntas sobre o assunto. Algo parecido sobre erros que geram exceções de Null ([veja como ficou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/nullpointerexception/info)).

Vamos começar? [Fiz um *stub*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/undefined/info) para alguém pesquisar e começar fazer, vamos ver como esse caso se sai.

Estou começando fazer de [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) e [exceção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o), ainda preciso organizar mais, estou pegando as mais fáceis.

Estou aproveitando e dando alguma melhorada nas descrições atuais. Por isso estou colocando um "Ver também" para indicar *tags* relacionadas, quando na verdade a instrução de uso já não manda usar outras *tags* relacionadas*.

Estou tentando por em prática algo parecido com o discutido em [Podemos ter perguntas "oficialmente" canônicas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7904/101), que não foi um sucesso mas não foi reprovado.

Discutam até onde isso ajuda e quando começa ser ruim para a comunidade.

Vamos começar melhorar o uso das wikis de *tag*?

Comment: Excelente ideia.

Comment: Era para o sistema já fazer isso automaticamente. Mas é uma boa mesmo.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. como o sistema faria automaticamente?

Comment: Não tenho ideia, Maniero. Não sei a metodologia utilizada pelo pessoal do Stack. Mas eu sugeriria que o sistema fizesse um tipo de organização de forma automatizada. Pegando as principais respostas, e agrupando por ordem de votos, etc ... Mas é apenas a opinião de um leigo.